# Does Epyc 2 have an equivalent to DDIO?

Tags: hardware

Does Epyc 2 (Rome) (specifically a 7402P in my case) have anything equivalent to Intel's DDIO, where PCIe devices doing DMA can transfer directly to last-level cache? Or do DMA accesses all go directly to DRAM? What happens if it's a DMA write and the data is already present in some caches in the system?

Comment: Good question, but probably too specialized to get an answer here. You'd likely be best off asking AMD directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD lacks support for DDIO.

For this reason AMD is not vulnerable to NetCAT: https://www.techpowerup.com/259096/new-netcat-vulnerability-exploits-ddio-on-intel-xeon-processors-to-steal-data

Comment: Thanks. The article doesn't explicitly mention Epyc 2, but it's published in Sep 2019 and Epyc 2 was released in Aug 2019, so I guess it would have mentioned it if AMD had added it to Epyc 2.